# How to disable trackpoint without disabling left and right click on a Thinkpad?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

I am currently using a Lenovo Thinkpad E560.  I want to disable the buggy trackpoint but when I do, the physical left and right click buttons are disabled along with it.  The touchpad still allows me to do left and right clicks but I would still like to use the physical buttons.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Do you see an ultranav icon in the control panel (or under mouse)? Did you download the driver directly from Lenovo or somewhere else?

Comment: One other thing you could do is take the red cap off. You can just pull it off. This might help you.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what settings Window you do get. Also, could you post the version number of your Ultranav driver and utility (these are probably two separate programs)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 7, this works:

Control Panel → Mouse → UltraNav. 
You should get the window shown below.

There, select **Enable TrackPoint** and toggle **Use advanced features only**  (see below).
Then click "Settings" …

[image: Mouse Properties → UltraNav]

You should get the window shown below. 
Under "Choose Scrolling or Magnifying Glass Function", select **Neither**  (see below).  (Then click "OK".)

[image: TrackPoint Properties]

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I am not given those options.  I am currently using the most recent Ultranav driver on an E560 Thinkpad.  If you suggest I try to use a different driver, I could.